# Cannot flash a Netgear R8000 router with Tomato or DD-WRT firmware,

Tags: router, dd-wrt, tomato

I purchased a new Netgear R8000 but cannot flash it with Tomato (Shibby or Advanced) or DD-WRT (Kong).

Any time I try to use the initial image I receive an error message stating that the firmware is not compatible with the router. As best as I can tell Netgear R8000 is supported by both Tomato and DD-WRT.

Does anyone know how I can go about debugging this? Or if there was a new version of the Netgear R8000 which was released which isn't compatible?

The current Netgear R8000 router firmware is version v1.0.4.18 and I cannot seem to flash it with any of these alternative firmware release:

**Advanced:**

- [tomato-R8000-1.28.AT-ARM7-3.4-140-initial-64K.chk](https://advancedtomato.com/downloads/router/r8000)
- [tomato-R8000-1.28.AT-ARM7-3.5-140-initial-64K.chk](https://advancedtomato.com/downloads/router/r8000)

**Shibby:**

- [tomato-R8000-1.28.ARM--134-initial-64K.chk](https://www.myopenrouter.com/download/tomato-firmware-shibby-netgear-r8000-initial)

**Kong:**

- [dd-wrt.K3_R8000.chk](http://www.desipro.de/ddwrt/K3-AC-Arm/)

Comment: What revision of the hardware do you have?  There should be a label on the device that indicates this information

Comment: As far as I know there is only one revision of the R8000. The model number is just R8000. It's not like other models where it had something like R7000v2, for example. Is there some differentiator I should be looking for?

Comment: Did you try the version from the [DD-WRT Router Database](https://dd-wrt.com/support/router-database/) (chk file)?

Comment: @harrymc, you shouldn't load any images you find in the router database. Some are bricksville, it's been discussed alot in their forums, but for whatever reason they have not fixed it. Stable releases from https://ftp.dd-wrt.com should be used. But alas it seems to be down when I checked it.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart: Then how does anyone find a good version?

Comment: @harrymc: according to the dd-wrt developers the last time I was on their forums, it's the FTP site under stable releases. (Which is down right now) they say it should be used as a quick reference to see if your router is a WIP or has support. It would be nice if they told people that on the router database page. People with broadcom based chipsets are **HIGHLY** recommended to read the "peacock" announcement. If they don't wish to read it, they should have a j-tag handy.

Comment: Peacock thread - https://forum.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=296835